# How is it better to make a button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add a 'fancy' button to my page. I see two possibilities:

- an `a` element with a picture as background and add a javascript function to the click event.

or

- an `img` element and add a javascript function to the click event.

What is your opinion ? Which one is the better way to do it and why ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Other options include:

- A link that styled to look like a button using a background image
- A Button element that is styled with a background image and no border.
- An Input element with type submit or button styled with a background image and no border.

I find that that button element works the best, particularly if you want rollover hover effects.

jQuery UI has a button plug-in that will style pretty much any kind of interactive element into a fancy button.

Answer (score 1):

Wherever possible, UI elements should be defined as CSS backgrounds. They are not part of the site content, so they don't really need to be indexed by search engines.

Semantically-speaking an `A`-tag implies a link, and therefore the event should be hooked up to the `A`-tag, not the image.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you're trying to do.

On my project, we have a form that we want to submit using a button rather than javascript, so we're inserting a button element.

```
<button type="submit">Sign Out</button>
```

Then you can style the button using CSS.

Other than that, we use images for non-form buttons and javascript for the functionality behind them.

Comment: [`<button>` elements may not have `<a>` element descendants](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-button-element.html#the-button-element).

Comment: What is the purpose of an a tag within the button?  That seems redundant, and possibly counter-productive (the link may try to cause a get, canceling out the button).

Comment: Better?  Our HTML validator has never complained about it, but I'll remove it from our page anyway.  Whoever added it is just using it for styling.  I'll be updating our CSS too.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @eamason9629, much better, your change was done before the changes were tracked, so I'm making a null change so that I can remove the down-vote.

Answer (score 1):

The first one. You have more options to style it, and it's easier to "theme" it as well. Imaging a "dark theme" and a "light theme", using CSS you can easily keep the same HTML but have totally different styles and images for your button. In some browsers, images are not necessary; you can easily create your button using pure CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by 'fancy' button but first look into what you're able to do with CSS, look for example at http://hellohappy.org/css3-buttons/ or http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#buttons .

If you want something fancier than that you should define a link in HTML, with and anchor tag since that's semantically correct and set it's background to an image with CSS. I don't see any reason to use Javascript for the click event as long as you simply want to make A GET request to some other page.

Answer (score 0):

Semantically, `<button>` and `<input type="button|submit|reset" />` elements are the correct choice for interactive elements within the page.

If you're simply styling a link to *look* like a button, then continue to use an `<a>` element, but define some styles and use a class, such as `<a class="button">`.

Pretty much [any element can be made into a button](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#button), and if you use the correct attributes it will maintain semantics.

The following are semantically identical, but the `<img>` requires JS support:

```
<!-- the image is of some fanciful text -->
<img src="some/image.jpg" alt="Continue" role="button" tabindex="0" />
<input type="image" src="some/image.jpg" alt="Continue" />
```

If you simply have a decorative image that doesn't affect the content, you could use a `span` or `div` that's styled with CSS:

```
<span role="button" tabindex="0" class="button continue-button">Continue</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can get that effect with plain CSS, no need for JS unless you want to call a function of some sort, and to spazz the button there is no need for a JS function.

You can simply use CSS actions (not sure they are named this way) like active, hover, focus, etc...

here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/RQucV/2/

it has a red color for background at first, changes to blue while clicking and becomes purple when visited. this is possible because i used a 'a' tag which has these properties.

i only changed the background color, but you can also changes many other elements, such as font, background image, margins, borders, you name it.

i think its cleaner to use pure CSS because of the JS clutter. if you want to add more scripts later, something bad is bound to happen when the browser has too much scripting to do. besides, parsing CSS might actually be faster than JS.

Just another tip if you go with pure CSS: not all browsers handle CSS the sameway, i highly recommend appending a "reset.css" to your stylesheet in order to make it play along the sameway in every browser you use.

hope it helps!